# how to fill an array with a fixed pattern vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to fill an array with a fixed pattern number sequence such as every x number of an element needs to add 1.

I tried to use `for to step`, as in:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test_Array()
    Dim Myarray(1 To 10) As Double
    Dim Element As Double
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    For Element = LBound(Myarray) To UBound(Myarray) Step 2
        Myarray(Element) = i
        i = i + 1
    Next Element    
End Sub
```

The result is as follows:

```
Myarray=[1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0]
```

But between each step needs to be populated with the previous element as the next example:

```
Myarray=[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]
```

I don't know if `for to step` is the best choise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
Const STEP_SIZE As Long = 2
Dim Myarray(1 To 10) As Double
Dim Element As Long

For Element = LBound(Myarray) To UBound(Myarray)
    Myarray(Element) = Application.Ceiling(Element / STEP_SIZE, 1)
Next Element
```